# how to execute python scripts from browser

Tags: django, python-2.7, matplotlib

i have several python scripts that plot maps based on some data stored in a postgresql database ( i use matplotlib for this), i need to execute these scripts from a web browser, knowing that the user should have the ability to visualize the result he needs ( i mean the map) according to the conditions he specifies, for example in the web page there have to be a form that specifies the date, the zone... of data , there have to be interactions with the database.
so is it possible ? how can i proceed ? shall i use a framework like django ? any ideas ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Yes, you can archive it with django. You probably should start from django tutorial. https://www.djangoproject.com/start/

Answer (score 0):

As @Wpedrak said, its pretty straight, you can use a view for that, manage the results, and then build the html with that results. Do this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: thank you @javier , since i have some spatial data in my database, am i gonna need geodjango or just django ?

Comment: You will have it easier if you use geodango.